# MySQL: Search multiple columns with single input (GoogleMaps Style)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I have a database loaded with [geonames's data](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) for the US. I want to perform a query on that table to find the closest match from a single input that has a more or less the same functionality as Google Maps (i.e. the user may input a zip code, a comma separated hierarchical address like 'Nevada, Las Vegas' or a combination of both).

So far I've added FULLTEXT indexes to the relevant fields of the table, and performing a query from the input like this:

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE MATCH(country_code, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1, admin_code1, admin_name2, admin_code2) AGAINST (?);
```

Where ? is replaced by the input by a php script. Altough it kinda works, it does not perform as expected, it doesn't put the most relevant matches first and needs a full word to start finding matches (I tried with wildcards but got worse). I also tried splitting the input if it had commas but the logic of the query started to get messy and couldn't produce a better performing script.

Is there a way to search this database in such broad terms for matches?

I'm querying the database via AJAX so I need it to start searching even if the word is not completed yet (I'm using jQuery's typeahead).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `string_to_be_searched` text with your text.

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE 
instr(concat_ws(" ",country_code, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1,
admin_code1, admin_name2, admin_code2),"string_to_be_searched")>0;
```

Comment: It did the trick! Thanks! I read the doc pages on INSTR and CONCAT_WS and although I managed to understand what they do separately I still don't understand pretty well how this accomplishes what I wanted.

Could you explain a little more?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Also in the final version I've changed the " " for a ", " to make it work, I figured it was the expected separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
FULLTEXT(country_code, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1...)
```

will let your `MATCH` work.  However...  Be aware of the limitations of FULLTEXT:  It searches only for "words" of some min word length,

Comment: I've declared the indexes already, my question was about how to perform the search when I don't know in advance in which column the answer to the query is located.

Comment: Did you had several 1-col indexes?  Or one index with many columns?

Comment: I've tried both, now I'm using a single index over many columns

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is to search registers that match, but you're not ordering them..

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(country_code, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1, admin_code1, admin_name2, admin_code2) AGAINST (?) AS relevance FROM places WHERE MATCH(country_code, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1, admin_code1, admin_name2, admin_code2) AGAINST (?) ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```